# Onclick listener with Scale Gesture

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a textview on which i have applied a pinch zoom gesture which increase/decrease the size of text view on zoom. I also want to apply an onclick listener on it but when i applied that onclick not working. I have searched on internet but no solution found. Anyone help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```html
package com.zeeshanfirstapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v("ACtion", "Clicked");
            }
        });

        final ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float size = textView.getTextSize();

                float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();

                float product = size*factor;
                textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);
                textView.invalidate();

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

            }
        });

        View.OnTouchListener listener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

        textView.setOnTouchListener(listener);

    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide some of your code, so that we can look for bugs there

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will.update my question soon. Thanks

Comment: @SebastianWalla, i have posted my code, please check. Cheers

Comment: Calling textView.setOnTouchListener twice so first listener is overwritten?  Needs one listener that deals with both types of gesture.

Answer (score 0):

You should perform your view adjustments in onCreateView, since the view might not be fully created when onCreate() is called.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Ok i will try my code in oncreateview but of my research i found that ontouch event is blocking my onclick listener but i can't figure out how to solve this

Comment: Can you post your code on github ... perhaps some of us can play around with it to help get you a solution.

Comment: Ok i will post tomorrow. Please check out. I will update my question